# How to set a static property on a class in Kotlin for Javascript

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I have a situation where I need to define a static property on a class in Kotlin and when its compiled to Javascript have it become a true static field on that class. In this situation companion objects do not work.

For example, if I have an abstract class and its implementing class like below:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass{
  abstract val id: Int
}

class MyClass: MyAbstractClass(){
  override val id: Int = 1 //I want this to actually be "static" on the MyClass
}
```

The Javascript that this compiles down to is this:

```
function MyAbstractClass() {
}

function MyClass() {
  MyAbstractClass.call(this);
  this.id_jz5fma$_0 = 1;
}

Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, 'id', {
  get: function () {
    return this.id_jz5fma$_0;
  }
});
```

But what I need it to compile down to is this:

```
function MyAbstractClass() {
}

function MyClass() {
  MyAbstractClass.call(this);
}

MyClass.id = 1;
```

So that the `id` field does actually statically exist on `MyClass` without having to make a new instance of `MyClass`.

I've tried using a companion object but that creates a separate object/function called `MyClass$Companion` and then assigns the `id` field to that and never actually assigns it statically to `MyClass`.

How can I go about setting true static fields like this in Kotlin?

Comment: If you compile to the JVM there is a `@JvmStatic` annotation. Maybe there is an equivalent of this for JS?

Comment: Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18891

Comment: You can declare a static variable on a class but you cannot declare a abstract static variable. There is no such thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now we don’t have a direct way to do it, so I’ve created issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18891

As a workaround, you can write a function like that:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> addStaticMembersTo(source: Any) {
    val c = T::class.js.asDynamic()
    val ownNames = js("Object").getOwnPropertyNames(source) as Array<String>
    val protoNames = js("Object").getOwnPropertyNames(source.asDynamic().constructor.prototype) as Array<String>

    for (name in ownNames + protoNames) {
        c[name] = source.asDynamic()[name]
    }
}
```

And use like:

```
class A {
    companion object {
        init {
            addStaticMembersTo<A>(object {
                val bar = 1
                fun foo() {}                
            })
        }
    }
}
```

or even make companion object's members available as a static member of class:

```
class B {
    companion object {
        val bar = 1
        fun foo() {}                

        // should be at the end of companion object
        init {
            addStaticMembersTo<B>(this)
        }
    }
}
```

The full example available here:
https://try.kotl.in/#/UserProjects/uube1qikg3vsegtnefo0ad0jag/30f1qf87dt5k5vjhciirt4t108