# Is there any way to write Kotlin code to generate javascript like "AppComponent.annotations"

Tags: javascript, angular, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I'm trying to use Kotlin to write angular JavaScript code. Here is some valid Javascript code for angular:

```
const AppComponent = function () {
    this.title = 'Angular Hello World Demo'
};

AppComponent.annotations = [new ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'hello-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css']
})];
```

But I can't write proper Kotlin code to generate such form of JavaScript code.

I tried to use companion object:

```
class MyComponent {
   companion object {
       val annotations = ...
   }
}
```

But it actually generates

```
function MyComponent() {}
function AppComponent$Companion() {
    this.annotations = ...
}
```

which is not working.

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: I think it's duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955888/how-to-set-a-static-property-on-a-class-in-kotlin-for-javascript . @Freewind you can find a workaround there and feel free to vote the related issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18891

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a static property on a class in Kotlin for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955888/how-to-set-a-static-property-on-a-class-in-kotlin-for-javascript)